# Spring-mvc-showcase Errors

Tags: spring-mvc, sample

I ran the spring-mvc-showcase from Netbeans 7.3 and got the following error, I haven't changed any code from the downloaded samples, what should I do to fix it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found out why, it's GlassFish that caused the problems, when I ran it with Tomcat everything worked fine.